# Are banks willing to lend money to one-man APP startups?

Tags: loans, banking, start-up, lending

I am one person building a social-media-ish APP. I am 2 years along. Let's say that it's 90% finished.

How do you get a bank to lend you money for this APP?

Comment: Where do you live? There are often government programs to help new small businesses secure funding. The program provides advice to you and some assurances to the bank.

Comment: I just looked it up, my (German) banks offer loans that specifically targeted at people who want to start a business (which mainly works for them because as @KateGregory pointed out the state might help out new founders). However your business plan would have to be rather more specific than "App 90% finished", so  probably you'd need to give more details to make this answerable.

Comment: I live in chicago illinois, USA.

Comment: Consider bootstrapping. Unless you expect this app to have a clear profitable path in the short term, it's unlikely saddling yourself with debt is going to help. You don't need to pay for big-iron servers, for example, if you only have 1-100 people using the app. Most people are surprised with how many concurrent users can be supported with relatively cheap hosting bills. Try real hard to self-fund until your business has revenue and can support itself.

Comment: One thing that might be an issue: the 'one' part of 'one-man'.  Whoever is giving you a loan needs to consider the chance that you might, well, disappear in one way or another.  If you are the only person involved, where does that leave their investment?

Comment: What does APP stand for?

Comment: @hobbs I think they mean app as in application. I don't know why they capitalized it.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor So this isn't about Authorised Push Payment fraud?

Answer (score 14):

Two options:

1. Personal loan. In this case the bank doesn't care what you're using the money for. You just ask for money and promise to repay and do with the money whatever you want. Usually these loans are the most expensive (since they're the riskiest for the banks). Example of such a loan would be a credit card.
2. Business loan. You're coming to the bank and asking them to fund your business. The loan is for a specific purpose which you describe in clear terms, including providing a business plan and a clear explanation how this business is going to be able to repay the loan. The banks will then do their due diligence on your business plan and if it makes sense to them they'll approve the loan.

In both cases (personal and business) banks may want you to provide collateral and/or guarantees. Mortgaging property that the bank can repossess may make it less risky for the bank, lowering the cost of the loan for you. For example, a second mortgage or HELOC on your home.

Comment: I'm not at all an expert, but aren't business loans more targeted at *established* businesses looking to extend (e.g., upgrading an existing factory etc.)? Do banks really provide what is effectively angel funding for a business that's not even operational yet?

Comment: @xLeitix While those are common, most small businesses also need loans to get started. The alternative is venture capital, where the underwriters get shares of the company. But I think this is mostly for businesses that have higher aspirations (the investors hope for you to go public or be acquired so their shares will have value). If you're opening a pizza place, you get a small business loan.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. Still doubtful to me whether OP's social media app business would be able to produce a business plan that's secure enough for a bank loan, but it's good, clear answer to the original question.

Comment: @xLeitix One-man shops developing mobile apps is probably a pretty common business these days -- the digital equivalent of opening a small restaurant. I'll bet banks have established processes for evaluating them.